# Maven dependency generates custom rest endpoints

Tags: java, maven, sdk

I am building SDK for my system. It's going to be maven dependency. I would like to know if it is possible to declare custom endpoints inside my SDK project.

For example client wish to connect with us. He/She implements our maven dependency and it will automatically generates static custom endpoints. 
Me as a product owner have to ask only client base url, cause SDK declares all resource endpoints automatically.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you know the way your clients will deploy application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved this problem by using rpc instead of rest :)